# ZXingWidgetController shows a blank screen when loaded

Tags: objective-c, ios, zxing

I am using Xcode 4.1, on iOS Simulator 4.3

I have imported the ZXing library into my project as per the instructions in their README.

When I try to load the controller all I see is a white screen with a Cancel button at the bottom. I know the simulator can't take photos but the controller is then supposed to let you choose an image to decode from the photo library. Has anyone had this issue or has any ideas on what is causing it?

```
ZXingWidgetController *widController = [[ZXingWidgetController alloc] initWithDelegate:self showCancel:YES OneDMode:NO];
QRCodeReader* qrcodeReader = [[QRCodeReader alloc] init];
NSSet *readers = [[NSSet alloc ] initWithObjects:qrcodeReader,nil];
[qrcodeReader release];
widController.readers = readers;
[readers release];
[self presentModalViewController:widController animated:YES];
[widController release];
```

[image: This is what I'm seeing]

EDIT: Forgot to mention, there are pictures on the simulator that I loaded already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the controller is then supposed to let you choose an image to
>   decode from the photo library

Where did you see this? It's not in the `README` or the code.

The widget doesn't provide an image picker backup. The old Barcodes app (found in `cpp/iphone/legacy/Barcodes_original`) did but the current Barcodes app doesn't. If you need this, you'll have to implement it yourself. The old Barcodes app might be useful as guide, to some extent.

Comment: I must have been thinking about the old version. Thanks!

Comment: If anyone is curious, I ended up using ZBar instead, http://zbar.sourceforge.net/ It has the capability to choose from the image library.